# Send multiple props across components React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-props, react-state

I am trying to send two variables from the Component 'Game' to the Component 'App' but I am unsure how to send more than one prop at a time.

This what I have:

```
//App Component

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      score: 0,
    }

    this.changeScore = this.changeScore.bind(this)
  }

  changeScore(newScore) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      score: prevState.score + newScore
    }))
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Game onClick={this.changeScore}/>
        <Score score={this.state.score}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

```
//Game Componenet 

class Game extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            score: 0,
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }

    handleClick() {
        console.log('Clicked')
        this.props.onClick(this.state.score)

    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}> Score Button </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

```
//Score Component

class Score extends Component {


    render() {

        const score = this.props.score

        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Score: {score}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

With this I am able to send the prop 'score' from 'Game' to 'App' but I was wondering if it was possible to send more then just the one prop, such as 'score' and a new variable, 'count' with the same button press, to ultimately be able to display both 'score' and 'count' in the 'Score' Componenet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure you can, just update the function you defined in the Parent App component to accept two arguments.

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      score: 0,
      count: 0
    }

    this.changeScore = this.changeScore.bind(this)
  }

  changeScore(newScore, count) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      score: prevState.score + newScore,
      count: prevState.count + count
    }))
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Game 
           onClick={this.changeScore} 
           score={this.state.score} 
           count={this.state.count}
        />
        <Score score={this.state.score} count={this.state.count}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Game.js** //refactored since it doesnt need to use state

```
const Game = ({ onClick, count, score }) => {
   const newScore = score + 10
   const newCount = count + 1
   return (
       <button onClick={() => onClick(newScore, newCount)}>Score</button>
   )
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was some way to do it but seemed to have a lot of trouble finding what I was looking for. This looks much nicer as well, Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely send more than one prop at a time. Here's the example that you've described:

```
<Score
    score={this.state.score}
    count={this.state.count}
/>
```

And in your Score component:

```
class Score extends Component {


    render() {

        const score = this.props.score;
        const count = this.props.count;

        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Score: {score}</h1>
                <h1>Count: {count}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```